# How to find how many tweets are extended tweets in Twitter Python with Twitter search API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, twitterapi-python

I don't know how to count or even find tweets that are extended tweets. I have used Twitter Search API to search for random tweets, but my main problem is that I couldn't find extended tweets from 1000 tweets. So, could you help me out and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import tweepy
import keys

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.consumer_key, keys.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(keys.access_token, keys.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# this will search the term in random tweets
tweets = api.search(q='Covid', count=1000)

count = 0

# this should check if there are extended tweets in tweets
for tweet in tweets:
    if (tweet_mode='extended') in tweet:

        # if there are any extended tweets then it should count it
        count += 1

print("Number of extended tweets: ", count)
```

Comment: Which python package are you using ? (ie. what does your import statement look like)

Comment: I just changed my code to add more information. I think I am using Python 3.0

Comment: I have updated my code to reflect your new information @Hamma Khan

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that tweepy has changed their api search functions. With the current version of tweepy (`4.12.1`), you need to use `api.search_tweets()`. 

If you do not specify the `tweet_mode` parameter, the `search_tweets` method will default to `compatibility mode` (compat). If you want to retrieve [extended tweets](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/extended_tweets.html), you need to specify the parameter `tweet_mode='extended'`.

Please note that when you use `tweet_mode='extended'` that the text of tweet can be found using `.full_text`, whereas in compatibility mode, the text of the tweet is found using `.text`.

Here is an example using the **extended mode**:

```py
import tweepy
import keys

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.consumer_key, keys.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(keys.access_token, keys.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

tweets = api.search_tweets(q='Covid', count=1000, tweet_mode='extended')

for i, tw in enumerate(tweets):
    print(i, "-", tw.full_text)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 - RT @graeme_0: Things are at the point where my level of DGAF has jumped up considerably re: not tolerating covid deniers, online and IRL.…
1 - RT @MarieSnyder27: 386 experts studying Covid in 112 countries came to a consensus on what needs to be done to END Covid. Can we please ben…
2 - sou tao ruim de desapegar de coisas irrelevantes tipo, ainda tenho o número e assisto os status do cara do salão q minha turma do ensino médio queria alugar p festa de formatura, me formei tem 2 anos e por causa da covid acabamos não comemorando, e mesmo ficando triste c os +
3 - @eefbeloathed @WhyYouSoooSalty @amoraobscura @MattWalshBlog You're talking to the same people who think people didn't die of covid if they had pre existing conditions. There is no reasoning with them.
4 - RT @TheRickyDavila: A reminder that Steven Mnuchin funneled $500B of PPP Covid relief loans and gave millions to himself, Kushner, Devin Nu…
5 - RT @vahtomah: @AlineBack1 @LeoMaranhao22 eles tentam de tudo.....até  volta da covid tem!!
...
...
...
```

Despite specifying that you want 1000 tweets, the code above **only returns 100** tweets. With the new api, if you want more than 100 tweets, then you have to use `Cursor`.

Here is how you would go about getting **more than 100 tweets** using **[Pagination](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v1_pagination.html)**:

```py
# Replace with your own search query
query = 'Covid -is:retweet'

# Replace the limit=1000 with the maximum number of Tweets you want
limit = 1000


for i, tweet in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, 
                                        q=query,
                                        lang="en",
                                        result_type='recent',
                                        tweet_mode='extended',
                                        count=100).items(limit)):
    print(i, tweet.id)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 - 1591615406556545025
1 - 1591615405587587073
2 - 1591615404346339332
3 - 1591615403264192513
4 - 1591615402773450752
5 - 1591615400441446402
6 - 1591615399929741312
7 - 1591615397052170241
8 - 1591615395819323392
9 - 1591615395529904128
10 - 1591615394971787266
11 - 1591615394476920834
12 - 1591615391583080449
13 - 1591615387766226944
14 - 1591615387271061504
15 - 1591615386956750848
16 - 1591615385316499457
17 - 1591615380564627456
18 - 1591615375900577793
19 - 1591615375397257218
20 - 1591615373690146818
21 - 1591615371563483136
22 - 1591615371483774976
23 - 1591615369604730880
24 - 1591615368891695106
...
996 - 1591613838834688001
997 - 1591613838226608128
998 - 1591613837656064001
999 - 1591613835676377088
```

Comment: I had originally indented in my code and it is still not working. I don't know how to ident here. So, it is definitely not an indentation problem.

Comment: Have updated my code to reflect the updates you provided

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code and explanation help quite a lot in understanding extended tweets.